# How could a new world war happen without ending civilization?

Tags: science-fiction, nuclear-war

It's generally accepted that a total nuclear war would be the end of human civilization.  I want to develop a world similar to ours, but with conditions that would allow for a world-spanning conflict that *doesn't* go nuclear.

My ideas were:

- All the countries sent strike teams to sabotage all opposing countries' nuclear arsenals simultaneously, leaving everyone without functional weapons, or
- A UN-like body issues a decree that all nuclear weapons have to be disassembled and their nuclear materials used for energy generation, and has the means to enforce this decree.

I feel that both ideas strain credulity, so I was hoping for a more reasonable mechanism.  So my question is:

**In a world similar to our modern Earth, how could a world war occur without using nuclear weapons?**

Comment: The world isn't going to end even if all humans die.

Comment: Define the "world ending", please. While the effect of all nukes detonating would be catastrophic, it's not likely that all humans will die from it.

Comment: Part of the concept of MAD is that anything upsetting the balance of power (like one country attempting a covert strike to take out another country's nuclear arsenal) triggers massive retaliation.  So covert teams "taking out" each others' nuclear weapons isn't really tenable.  (Also, the UN doesn't issue decrees.)

Comment: You aren't the first to come to such a conclusion.  Albert Einstein is credited with a quote: "I know not with what weapons World War III will be fought, but World War IV will be fought with sticks and stones."

Comment: WWn and WWn+1 aren't human extinction events, they are part of tools often used in politic. If there is one important thing that we learn about history is that it repeats.

Comment: Needs support for the assertation that "a total nuclear war would be the end of human civilization" is generally accepted.  Some people think this is the case, but I don't think their number includes many who've actually studied the question.

Comment: I voted to close this because there are quite simply **too many** possible solutions to the question. @Arson, all you need to do it look at any of the **hundreds** of works of fiction — in books, films, computer games — that deal with World War Three and there you will have prototypes for your story. One of my old favourites — that specifically deals with the Weapons of Mass Destruction issue —  is Red Storm Rising by Tom Clancy, in my own opinion one of his better works before he lost his touch and started writing garbage.

Comment: The main reason that the parties involved will keep nuclear weapons and other WMD out of the conflict is simply because they do not **want** them to be used, for the very reason you postulate at the start: it will destroy or at least seriously harm civilization to the point where it is simply not worth it.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the world wars (with relation to nuclear weapons) was that they were *total wars*.  In total war, all resources of a country are put towards the war effort - which means that it's unlikely in the extreme that nuclear weapons would be held back, particularly if one side was at risk of losing everything.

Unfortunately, neither of your proposed methods of removing nukes from the battlefield is particularly likely to *work* in a world war situation, because even if the entire, many-thousands of weapons world stockpile of warheads were destroyed or disabled, we haven't forgotten how to make *more*.  In fact, getting rid of the weapons would likely result in the war going nuclear *faster*, because whoever got first strike capabilities would have an enormous advantage.

So what's the solution?  Pretty simple:

**Give the Opposing Powers Nuclear Countermeasures**

This was what all the ruckus was about during Reagan's Star Wars development, and many authors have written on this subject.  The way you make a nuclear war non-world-ending is to have a never- or seldom-fails countermeasure to deal with the nukes.  So some scientist comes up with a mechanism by which, say, city-spanning force fields can be constructed and powered that would successfully resist a nuclear strike.  Or some sort of field that totally inhibits fission within its operating area, turning any bomb that enters its region of effect into a dud.

Important caveat - the development of this technology has to either be so fast as to be deployable in weeks, or a part of a multilateral development effort by the world powers before the war starts.  Otherwise, you get into balance of power issues.  As evidenced many times in the nuclear planning of the former USSR and the United States, if one side looked like it was on the verge of developing an insurmountable advantage, the other side would have no choice but to launch an immediate first strike.

So everyone has nuclear-chain-reaction deadening fields in place over their cities and portable units for their armies and navies - and we're back to using good old-fashioned bombs and bullets.

*Edit:*

It is also important to note, however, that the conditions that pertained during the second and especially the first world war no longer do so.  The major powers have *enormous* force multipliers that make artillery look silly and old-fashioned.  Advanced fuel-air explosives could flatten cities as readily as nuclear weapons.  A single advanced bomber could take out an entire production facility, where a wing of bombers (or more) was necessary before.

Drones, smart bombs, orbital weapons - while the human race would definitely be likelier to survive, it still would not be a prolonged conflict.

Comment: May I add that "old-fashioned" artillery still has plenty of uses in modern warfare outside of the realm of mass destruction? I don't think you necessarily implied that it didn't; I just felt compelled to interject as a former USMC Artilleryman. Steel rainnnnn!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

## MAD

Mutually Assured Destruction. I can't fire a nuke at another country because they will fire back. It is highly unlikely that any *reasonable* country will use nukes, but nuclear war could still happen in the case of a madman being in control of nuclear weapons.

Remember that world war might not mean nuclear war.

Answer (score 1):

**Missile interception**, while not yet a viable technology, it may be one day possible to prevent nuclear missile strikes through the use off missile intercept systems which fire off a missile to collide with and destroy enemy missiles.

This technology is still in development, some recent tests have taken out mid range missiles. http://abcnews.go.com/International/us-conducts-successful-intermediate-range-missile-intercept-test/story?id=48575867

Here is the page on the THAAD Missile intercept system from the Lockheed Martin website:
http://www.lockheedmartin.com/us/products/thaad.html

Answer (score 0):

Why does a war need to involve nuclear missiles, or indeed any conventional armaments?

It is more likely that, at some level of human civilization, that such wars will be seen as unnecessarily destructive and wasteful, and social integration across geographical boundaries, and general global awareness, will make violent conflict especially territorial conflicts increasingly rare.

However, wars will still exist. Think trade wars, think wars across strata of society, or sectors of society, think guerilla style wars conducted by isolated extremists, of underground organisations of people spread thinly but held together using social media. Think wars of propaganda across social media, not trying to take over countries geopolitically, but trying to take over minds. Think of different philosophies and different beliefs untied to geography - there is plenty of scope for conflict and war, but nuclear war only makes sense in a geopolitical arena.

I think there is plenty of scope for non-nuclear conflicts in modern society and the very nature of global integration could easily make it worldwide. Not only that, but a such a world war could easily creep up upon us unexpectedly.

Comment: Nationalism is on the rise again, why do you think that people are going to become globally aware? Also you could say both World Wars crept up on us, but especially WW2. After WW1 people thought that no one would ever want to cause a war like that again, but someone did almost immediately.

Comment: @Braydon, I think increasing global awareness is inevitable, and the growing Nationalism that we see is actually the resistance to it but, in the process of resisting it, it is also recognising it. Not everyone will feel the same way about it, and there will be schisms, but these are increasingly less likely to be geopolitical: nationalists in one country will actually be more in line with nationalists in another country and both will be against the growing global hegemony. Conflict is inevitable, but nuclear war is not.

Comment: Actually nuclear war is almost inevitable. If it is possible, and you give it enough time, it will happen eventually. The only way it will not happen is if something makes it no longer possible, such as a defense to nuclear warheads. Also what is your basis for believing humans will abandon nationalism? I see no reason but wishful thinking. Tribal instincts will lead people to nationalism as long as their are nations.

Comment: I have never said that all humans will abandon nationalism. We will always value what makes us individual, but we will not see us as exclusively defined by nation, and awareness of more global issues will unite people in different ways. We will always be tribal, but we will not always define our tribe by geography.